# Does SO have too many questions and not enough answers?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, unanswered-questions

I've noticed recently that SO appears to have hit a critical mass such that there are too many questions, and they're coming in too fast. On any given day, I look at the front page and all I see are questions with 0-1 answers. Even more-so 1 answer with few, if any, upvotes (usually the answer is poor).

This results in a number of problems:

- Legitimate questions don't get enough exposure
- Not enough questions get answers
- Not enough questions get *good* answers

Is this a known problem? Not considered a problem? Is anything being done to address it (min rep to ask, more focused SE sites being accepted, etc.)?

I've heard from other developer friends that asking questions on SO isn't very useful anymore because few people, if anyone, ever see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're mistaking the new homepage algorithm for something else...

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

Comment: Have you noticed a change in the answer rate since the update?

Comment: @snorf yes, it went up.. the point is that, if you read the blog entry, we *suppress* things we believe have been "sufficiently answered" so other questions without answers have a chance to get some love

Comment: for example just in the last 30 minutes.. http://twitter.com/#!/jitbit/status/16048965728342018

Comment: Good enough for me. Thanks Jeff.